# If $AB + BA = 0$, what is $\operatorname{tr}(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is a regular square matrix with the dimension $n$ and $B$ is a square matrix with the dimension of $n$ and $AB + BA = 0$, find the trace of $B$.

From here, I can get this:

$AB = -BA$

$ABA^{-1} = -B$

But I just don't see how I should proceed, or if I am even on the right track. Any help with the solution is appreciated..

Comment: How do you know $A^{-1}$ exists?

Comment: @ZacharySelk It is given $\;A\;$ is *regular*

Comment: @DonAntonio I see. Even Wikipedia says that this usage is rare, lol. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_matrix

Comment: @ZacharySelk if a matrix is regular, it's determinant is non-zero, therefore it is invertible

Comment: @ZacharySelk Wiki must be high: just google "regular matrix" and you will see more than 100 million entries. Besides this, it is a regular (pun intended...) definition in many text books in linear algebra.

Comment: @DonAntonio Really, I have only seen "invertible". Thanks.

Comment: I've also only seen invertible, or non-singular.

Comment: do you know that similar matrices have the same trace?

Comment: @yes, that's just what I was thinking now.. I guess we could say that $B$ and $-B$ are similar? And therefore they have the same traces..

Answer (score 3):

We have 
$$
\operatorname{tr}(B)=\operatorname{tr} (ABA^{-1})=\operatorname{tr}(-B)=-
\operatorname{tr}(B).
$$
This implies $2\cdot \operatorname{tr}(B)=0$
For fields of characteristic not $2$ this means that $\operatorname{tr}(B)=0$, but for fields of characteristic $2$ this is not true.

Comment: but shouldn't the trace of be be equal to the trace of $-A^{-1}BA$?

Comment: But you said $ABA^{-1}=-B$, hence both sides have the same trace.

Comment: okay, can you just explain what *fields of characteristic* are?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)). For example, take the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ with $2$ elements.

Comment: @ccorn This looks much better now.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to use $\text{tr}XY=\text{tr}YX$ to rewwrite $\text{tr}ABA^{-1}$ to prove $\text{tr}B=\cdots$